# How to pass all properties of class to parent constructor class?

Tags: typescript, oop, typescript2.0

I have the following class:

```
export class FilterClassJournalConclusions extends FilterAbstract implements IFilterClassJournalConclusions {

  public class: number;
  public suffix: string;
  public number: number;
  public year: number;
  public subject: number;

  public constructor() {
    super();
    this.model = this.class;
  }

}
```

I need to pass all properties of class `FilterClassJournalConclusions` to parent constructor as object:

```
super({class: this.class, suffix: this.suffix...});
```

But it looks ugly and redundant, how to beautify it?

Comment: Maybe to use spread operator?

Comment: That will pass only undefined values anyway. Is this really what you want to do? This looks like an XY question. Tell us what you actualy want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access `this` before `super` is finished executing. This is because you *are* allowed to access the parent's properties inside the constructor. When I checked, I cannot even call `super({ a: this.a })` in a sample class. This makes sense because `this.a` could plausibly be initialized in the class as `a = this.b + 2` where `b` is a parent property!

All is not lost though! If you want the parent class to access the child, this can be done. Just be aware that `super` finishes before the child's constructor... so accessing the child in the parent's constructor will usually have unfortunate consequences.

Imagining that your `FilterClassJournalConclusions` is one of a few subclasses which define some values/conditions which we want to use to filter a subset out of a super big list of things, and the parent class `FilterAbstract` handles the fancy filtering logic; it just needs to know *how* to filter.

The generics in the example below allow the parent class to return values that are derived from the shape of the child class (if you go the route of having a parent access the child this usually becomes desirable).

Here's an example of how that can be done:

```
interface IFilterClassJournalConclusions {
  filterAttributes: { [key: string]: number | string };
}

class FilterAbstract<T extends IFilterClassJournalConclusions> {
  constructor() {};
  private get child(): T {
    return this as any; // cast this to the type of the child
  }
  biggestList(): any[] {
    return [{}, { class: 2 }, { year: 1999 }, { suffix: 'Jr.' }]
  }
  private matches(element: any): element is Partial<T['filterAttributes']> {
    return Object.keys(element).some(key => element[key] === this.child.filterAttributes[key])
  }
  filter(): Partial<T['filterAttributes']>[] {
    const results: Partial<T['filterAttributes']>[] = [];
    this.biggestList().forEach(element => {
      if (this.matches(element)) { 
        results.push(element); 
      }
    })
    return results;
  }
}

class FilterClassJournalConclusions extends FilterAbstract<FilterClassJournalConclusions> implements IFilterClassJournalConclusions {
  filterAttributes = {
    class: 'best highschool',
    year: 1999
  }
}

// note the type is Partial<{ class: string; year: number }>[]
const filtered = new FilterClassJournalConclusions().filter();

console.log(filtered); // [{ year: 1999 }]
```

In my opinion, that strategy is painful over time, and less preferable than applying composition over inheritance. That looks more like this:

```
interface IFilterClassJournalConclusions {
  filterAttributes: { [key: string]: number | string };
}

class Filterer{
  constructor() {};
  biggestList(): any[] {
    return [{}, { class: 2 }, { year: 1999 }, { suffix: 'Jr.' }]
  }
  private matches<T extends IFilterClassJournalConclusions>(definition: T, element: any): element is Partial<T['filterAttributes']> {
    return Object.keys(element).some(key => element[key] === definition.filterAttributes[key])
  }
  filter<T extends IFilterClassJournalConclusions>(filterWith: T): Partial<T['filterAttributes']>[] {
    const results: Partial<T['filterAttributes']>[] = [];
    this.biggestList().forEach(element => {
      if (this.matches(filterWith, element)) { 
        results.push(element); 
      }
    })
    return results;
  }
}

class FilterClassJournalConclusions implements IFilterClassJournalConclusions {
  filterAttributes = {
    class: 'best highschool',
    year: 1999
  }
}

// note the type is Partial<{ class: string; year: number }>[]
const filtered = new Filterer().filter(new FilterClassJournalConclusions());

console.log(filtered); // [{ year: 1999 }]
```